# Joomla 3.0 Component JS error in backend

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, joomla3.0

I am developing a Joomla 3.0 component. As sample I downloaded the com_hello component from the Joomla documentation.

The error I am occurring is that when I am checking the checkbox in the list of a view, I get an error message `TypeError: b is null`. This error occurred somewhere in the core.js.

Normally in 2.5, if I used the `JHtml::_('grid.id',$i,$item->id);` code and had `<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />` field in my form it worked fine.

I also looked in some components of the Joomla core, but I didn't find something that was missing or some other error.

Here is the code of the `default.php` of my view:

```
<?php

// NO DIRECT ACCESS TO THIS FILE
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_simplesuite'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm">
    <table class="adminlist">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th><input type="checkbox" name="checkall-toggle" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_CHECK_ALL'); ?>" value="" onclick="Joomla.checkAll(this);" /></th>
                <th><?php echo JText::_('COM_SIMPLESUITE_TAGCLOUD_ADMINISTRATOR_LIST_NAME'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo JText::_('COM_SIMPLESUITE_TAGCLOUD_ADMINISTRATOR_LIST_TAGS'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo JText::_('COM_SIMPLESUITE_TAGCLOUD_ADMINISTRATOR_LIST_ACTIONS'); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
            <tr class="row<?php echo $i%2; ?>">
                <td><?php echo $item->id; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo JHtml::_('grid.id',$i,$item->id); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $item->name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($item->tags) ? $item->tags : JText::_('COM_SIMPLESUITE_TAGCLOUD_ADMINISTRATOR_LIST_EMPTY'); ?></td>
                <td><a href="#">W</a><a href="#">X</a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?></td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the top of your script:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function () {
    if (typeof jQuery != 'undefined' && typeof MooTools != 'undefined') {

            Element.implement({
                slide:function (how, mode) {
                    return this;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

That's probably the mootols conflict that is being under resolution with the dev team.

Comment: You're using the com_hello component as I now understand. Well, the bad news is that the com_hello isn't designed to work properly with the current version of the platform - 3.0.1. It's a poor adaptation of an old component that even doesn't make use of the bootstrap framework. In order to get it to work, you have to almost recode it from scratch, I'm afraid. The proper way to code the default view, in this case, isn't the one used in the com_hello. Take a look at, for instance, the default view of com_weblinks, and you'll understand that perhaps you're loosing some precious time on this one.

Answer (score 6):

For your `<form>` element, ensure you have `id="adminForm"` also.  See http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#JavaScript for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
<?php echo JHtml::_('grid.checkall'); ?>
```

instead of this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkall-toggle" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_CHECK_ALL'); ?>" value="" onclick="Joomla.checkAll(this);" />
```

That worked for me.

Comment: It has worked for me too, i tried making change in Joomla com_hello plugin

Answer (score 0):

Add id="adminForm" into form. I spend a while to find it, had the same problem.

Forms that have name="adminForm" now also require id="adminForm".

see:

http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2#JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I added the following field and it worked for me

```
<input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="" />
```